# How to serialize or deserialize application/soap+msbin1 requests in PHP?

Tags: php, wcf, iis, soap, binary

Basically the subject. We have to call the SOAP Binary services from the PHP client and the server requires an "application/soap+msbin1" header + binary encoded content.

Is it possible to do this in PHP?

Comment: The binary encoding is used to, well, encode XML messages between WCF services, in a Microsoft-specific format. Can't the party you're supposed to call give you a plain old SOAP/XML endpoint?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it is government service :( How to encode XML in a Microsoft-specific format? Is there an example of a PHP/Python/Golang script?